# MS SQL - 3 'OR's within one OR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a View I created using Microsoft Dynamics 2011 and I'm now looking to turn this into SQL code to use within Excel.

[image]

I have gotten everything else to work except the OR clauses (the query doesn't return all the results that I am expecting). I'm very new to SQl and any help will be really appreciated.

```
AND      (Child.btb_childhealthlastlacmedical is NULL 
OR       Child.btb_childhealthlastlacmedical <= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())) 
AND      (Child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate is NULL 
OR       Child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate <= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())) 
AND      (Child.btb_childhealthlastopticiandate is NULL 
OR       Child.btb_childhealthlastopticiandate <= DATEADD(month, -24, GETDATE()))
```

**Final Edit** Solved By xQbert's solution below. Thank you so much!!

Comment: don't mix join notations.  meaning don't use , join and RIGHT OUTER join.  Remove the , and put the inner join desired (though I think a right outer makes more sense given the join though Family.)

Comment: So do you only want records that meet all 3 critiera?  or all records that meet any of the criteria?

Comment: and where is the active status criteria in your SQL?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something more like this. But you might possibly want and instead or or within the brackets. Not sure what you're looking for. But basically you need to separate statements with or instead of and

```
   AND  (Child.btb_childhealthlastlacmedical is NULL OR
     Child.btb_childhealthlastlacmedical <= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())) 
 OR
     (Child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate is NULL OR
     Child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate <= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())) 
 OR
     (Child.btb_childhealthlastopticiandate is NULL OR
     Child.btb_childhealthlastopticiandate <= DATEADD(month, -24, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm getting an error. Something about an incorrect syntax?

    Error during Execute
 37000(156)[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'is'.
37000(8180)[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.

Comment: Do you have anything else in the where clause before?

Comment: Weird, I'm getting more than 1000 results, when I'm expecting only 16.

Comment: what is your 'WHERE    Child.accountid=Family.accountid ' is that supposed to be a part of the join?

Comment: This is what my results should look like
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyT0v.jpg)

Comment: Its hard to say exactly unless i could actually run it on your system. Create an sql fiddle schema and i can have a look

Comment: WHERE Child.accountid=Family.accountid  is because both ANSI 92 and 89 standards are use in the from clause.  Don't use `,` notation (89) and `RIGHT JOIN` notation (92) standards at the same time.

Comment: oh yes, very well spotted. If you take @xQbert advice into account and include my where clause i think it might be better

Comment: we also need to note that if the right join is being used, limiting criteria on the matching records table should be placed on the join; or the outer join behaves like an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

This will return true if any field meets the criteria

```
AND ( COALESCE(Child.btb_childhealthlastlacmedical, 
      DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())) <= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()) 
OR COALESCE(Child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate , 
      DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())) <= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()) 
OR COALESCE(Child.btb_childhealthlastopticiandate , 
      DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())) <= DATEADD(month, -24, GETDATE()) 
)
```

You also want to change your RIGHT outer join to just a JOIN (sometimes called an inner join)  This is probably why you are getting more results than you expect.

Comment: Thanks Hogan, but I'm getting an error, saying **Incorrect Syntax Near '<'** which isn't much help to you I admit lol

Comment: Thanks, just tried it out, but I get exactly the same results as I was originally getting. Thank you though :)

Comment: @Robert -- well you don't us what you want but try my third query there... maybe that is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't mix join notations use the ANSI 92 standard (INNER JOIN, OUTER JOIN) not the 89 (comma notation)  your present join would exclude the records from the family table not in filtered contact.

--RIGHT OUTER JOINS mean that dbo.FilteredContactcontact is the table with all the records. And then records from dbo.filteredAccount that match those in child and then those in filteredBusinessUnit that match.  As such the fil.name filter belongs on the join.

The filters on the child table belong on the right table.  I'm really surprised no one else caught me on this...

```
SELECT Child.fullname AS Child
FROM dbo.FilteredBusinessUnit Fil
RIGHT JOIN dbo.FilteredAccount Family 
  ON Fil.businessunitid=Family.owningbusinessunit
RIGHT JOIN dbo.FilteredContact Child 
  ON Child.accountid=Family.accountid
WHERE (Child.btb_childhealthlastlacmedical is NULL 
   OR Child.btb_childhealthlastlacmedical <= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()) 
   OR Child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate is NULL 
   OR Child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate <= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())
   OR Child.btb_childhealthlastopticiandate is NULL 
   OR Child.btb_childhealthlastopticiandate <= DATEADD(month, -24, GETDATE()) )
 AND Child.customertypecode = 1  
 AND Child.owningbusinessunit = 'North West'
```

Note when using outer joins, any limiting criteria on tables aside from the "all records table (FilteredContactin this case)" should be placed on the join, or the outer join is negated and behaves like an inner join.

I'm not sure why you have the null checks if its because some records are null or if you had the null check to keep the records from the outer join.  If the latter then this way we don't need the null checks.  If the first then we need to keep the null checks.

Comment: Thank you for this. I've added a WHERE clause to get only "Active" records, but it seems to be ignoring this. Using your code I'm getting 126 rows of data, but this does include the 16 "Active" records I was getting with my Dynamics 'View'.

Comment: Ah I see a common mistake.  The filters you typically put in a where clause must be moved to the join when using outer join's .  otherwise the nulls get removed.  Which may be why you have the OR is null in the first place...

Comment: Hey xQbert. I tried your updated code and I'm now getting 1000s of records, so I added in a Child.customertypecode column and it seems that the "= 1" in the clause above is being ignored, because I'm getting "1"s and "2"s. 

Also, if I wanted to narrow the results down even more by specifying the Office name (business unit), where would I put the code `AND      Fil.name = 'North West'` ?

   Regarding nulls, I need to display these as sometimes the dates haven't been entered and I want to highlight this.. along with the other dates which are older than 12 months (or 24 months in one case).

Comment: I misread the right joins as left... I need to correct a few things.  The where clause now makes sense as the table aliased child is the "All records table" and any filters on it belong in the where clause.  The Fil.Name filter belongs on the join of Fil to Family. So the filter applies before the join allowing the null records from Child and Family to persist.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I realised that `AND Fil.name = 'North West'` doesn't work and instead I need `AND Child.owningbusinessunit = 'North West'` . I stuck this on the line below `AND Child.customertypecode = 1` however I now don't get enough results (3 rows).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirement for the childhealthlast* dates.  if any one value is missing or over 1/2 years you want it back? or only if all 3 are missing?  if any 1 we need to change some or's to ands and add ()'s  I've taken a stab at updating the query based on the fact you expect more records.

Comment: Solved!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: sorry it took so long!  Multiple misreadings and errors/issues.